# Webhook Response but not created

Tags: shopify, webhooks

When I'm trying to 'finalize' the creation of the installation process on my end, I decided to automatically create the necessary Webhooks through the API automatically so the Shop owner doesn't need to worry about it.

Seems to be working, however I do not see the Webhook installed under Preferences > Email .. Notifications . Its just blank with no Webhooks installed.

When I create the webhook, this is sample of the response I got back from the API

```
Array
(
   [address] => http://myapp.com/shopify/webhook?topic=products_create
   [created_at] => 2012-07-06T11:16:44-04:00
   [format] => json
   [id] => 1921476
   [topic] => products/create
   [updated_at] => 2012-07-06T11:16:44-04:00
)
```

So it appears to be sending me back a data response with an ID, but just not in the shops prefences, it does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the API to create a WebHook you will not see it in the Shop itself. You used to be able to see them, but merchants would be able to delete them by accident and that caused trouble. So now they remain hidden.

Use the API to query for your created WebHooks.

Comment: Ahhh okay. I remember creating them before and being able to see them. Actually, I was always worried about Shop owners deleting them thus breaking the app. Good to know. Thanks.